# ODBCCP32.DLL does not create Server DSN for 64-bit driver

Tags: c++, dll, odbc, installshield

I have a code that useDLL(ODBCCP32.DLL) and it executes `SQLConfigDataSource` method to add System DSN. Everything seems to be working correctly if the driver is 32-bit then it adds the Server DSN fine. But when the driver does not exists under ODBC (32-bit) but under ODBC(64-bit) it does not create the Server DSN even the driver name exists and it's correctly specified. Should I use different .dll for that?

Comment: Try to recompile your project in 64 bits

Comment: @Landstalker does it really matter? But i.e. I'd like to configure Server DSN for ms access which is 32-bit, and other driver which is 64-bit how can I do that? Are there any others dll that may I use? I do not believe if this is the cause of that.